# Do I need to weatherproof my outdoor conduit?

Tags: wiring

I recently installed some outdoor conduit, with weatherproof boxes and (the most expensive bits) raintight compression connectors. Because this is EMT conduit, set screw connectors were also available, but, obviously not wet rated.

I recently got to thinking, however, that THWN is, on its own, wet rated and the conduit merely serves as physical protection.

So, **do I need to install raintight/weatherproof connectors for conduit when the wires within are already wet rated?**

Comment: You do need fittings rated for a wet location. So yes the listed fittings are required.  It may sound silly especially if you have dug up or pulled a low point in outside conduit and found it full of water. Any time I have a long outside run I add drain holes in the boxes. Listed fittings do reduce the amount of water that can enter the pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Wet locations only require corrosion resistant materials. But I would use compression connectors outdoors anyway.

From the National Electrical Code

> **358.10 Uses Permitted.**
>
> (A) Exposed and Concealed. The use of EMT shall be permitted for both exposed and concealed work.
>
> (B) Corrosion Protection. Ferrous or nonferrous EMT, el-bows, couplings, and fittings shall be permitted to be in-stalled in concrete, in direct contact with the earth, or in areas subject to severe corrosive influences where protected by cor-rosion protection and approved as suitable for the condition.
>
> (C) Wet Locations. All supports, bolts, straps, screws, and so forth shall be of corrosion-resistant materials or protected against corrosion by corrosion-resistant materials.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Only outdoor electrical conduit should be used outdoors.

Water-resistant wire just resists water. It is not meant to be immersed in water. If your conduit or boxes fill up with water, it will short out and/or you will get leaks.

Comment: 1) It's EMT which can be installed outdoors. 2) The boxes are outdoor, *weather*proof boxes. 3) Obviously if it gets filled it will short. That's often why there is a drain hole provision.

Comment: You've never had underground conduit... Even PVC is full of water 99% of the time.

Comment: They make outdoor conduit for a reason. Ask any farmer who put standard conduit outside (and they all do at first) and they will tell you that eventually they get problems. I know of one family whose dog was electrocuted because they ran an electrical line to a garage with standard conduit.

Comment: @TylerDurden less about the conduit than using the conduit as the grounding path. But agreed; bad news.   In any case trying to keep outdoor  conduit from filling with water is a lost cause, you win that war with the water-rated wire.

Comment: @TylerDurden Out of curiosity, what exactly are you referring to when you say "standard conduit"? I'm actually unsure if you mean Sch 40 PCV, EMT, RMC, etc.

Comment: Also, concerning the outdoor ratedness of EMT, NEC 358.10(A)(2): [The use of EMT shall be permitted for both exposed and concealed work for the following:] In dry, damp, or wet locations.

Comment: Tyler ,EMT is outdoor conduit. The couplings & ends are what define it for use inside vs outside. Almost all underground conduit has water in the pipe! This is why conduit outside is listed as a wet location. The reason romex can not be used is because the paper causes a capillary action when wet and will start dripping inside the house (I have seen this a few times). If the wire is spliced under ground or in a wet location water proof splices are required. With a properly installed system The insulation on the wire will prevent it from shorting in water.